(Addon) check if exists an update for an addon?
I'm trying to implement a system that notifies the users when an update for my addon is available.
In this case my addon is uploaded to gumroad.
My thoughts about approaching this was:
I thought about directly type the current version of my addon in my addon page, so I can execute some kind of httprequest, get the text, and check if the version there was higher than the installed.
The problem:
It seems that the httprequest module is not installed by default with python (as I saw here (also tried it and effectively, is not installed)). So a question arises for me; if I use a python module that I have to install manually, I guess the user won't be able to execute in their side any function of that module? (or am I wrong?).
If so, then I simply don't know how to approach the problem without httprequest.
So, any idea about how to solve the problem?
Any idea is welcome, thank you so much

Blender is shipped with requests library.
C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\blender.exe" --factory-startup -b --python-expr "import requests; print(requests.__file__); print(requests.__version__)"
Blender 4.1.0 (hash 40a5e739e270 built 2024-03-26 02:02:39)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\4.1\python\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py
2.27.1


Aw, I should have tried my script inside Blender. I tried it in my python's console and since the default python installation didn't had it installed I thought Blender would neither had it. Thanks man, that makes everything easier.
